# Localization and drawables

Tags: android, resources, localization, drawable

I want to localize an image by adding the folder res/drawable-hdpi-no, but I get an error stating "invalid resource directory name".  What's up with this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As far as I remember, only certain res folders will work.
You need to call it drawable-[language code]-r[capitalised localisation code] if I remember rightly. Pretty sure it's one of the Android Tutorials.

Yeah here it is
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html

Comment: Thanx! I knew I'd seen that tutorial. I just couldn't find it. Though the solution to my direct problem is "res/drawable-no-hdpi" and not "res/drawable-hdpi-no"

Answer (score 46):

Each Android resource can have configuration parts in its resource name. For example you might have a plain image on

```
res/drawable
```

and a image for a high DPI screen on

```
res/drawable-hdpi
```

Here hdpi is a Screen pixel density configration. A list of supported Android resource configurtions can be found from here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

The order of configurations are **important**. They **must** be on specific order. Your original Norwegian language configuration is on a wrong place. Change

```
res/drawable-hdpi-no
```

to

```
res/drawable-no-hdpi
```

and it works.

Answer (score 31):

yes, it is possible by. drawable-de-rDE-ldpi,drawable-de-rDE-mdpi . use it

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly the **Android Studio UI** to create your `Android Resource Directory` and providing all parameters you want:

[image: Create Android Resource Directory]

then define all the parameters you need (Locale, Density, etc.)...

[image]

Then click on `OK` and your folder will be created correctly.