# How to get images with respect to the selection of custom Localization?

Tags: android, localization, drawable, android-resources

I am trying to implement  my app in  different languages. Text changes are fine but i didn't get any  idea of that images are retrieving with respect to  selection of locale(custom).

**i follow the below code:**

My string are put in resource folder: res/values-xx /string.xml

```
        Locale locale=new  Locale("xx");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

This is working fine for text. Let me know how to implement this. I just tried to put images in res/drawable-xx/some.png ,but it doesn't working for me. Please give me some suggestions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Finally i got the solution for it.Here xx is Language code.
This is very simple by declaring layout as layout-xx and your drawable folder should be declared as drwable-xx.

Answer (score 0):

This post may provide some insight on how your folder structure should be:

[Localization and drawables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442105/localization-and-drawables)