# Determine application drawable Language using Localisation settings on phone android

Tags: android, localization

I am using android localisation for determining the picture to display from drawable.  i create a drawable floder as follows

for hdpi in french

drawable-fr-hdpi

for hdpi in english

drawable-fr-hdpi

is it correct because the images displays using default only.

Comment: Check this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442105/localization-and-drawables> drawable-[language code]-r[capitalised localisation code]-

Example 
drawable-fr-rFR-hdpi
drawable-en-rEN-hdpi

Comment: drawable-fr-rFR-hdpi .. it remains in english

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for device selected language.

```
locale = Locale.getDefault();
```