# Drawables by country Android

Tags: android, resources, translation, drawable

I'm translating my apps to a few languages but now I'm struggling with a problem! I a few images with text on it, there is a way to provide drawable resources using country code? If I add the drawable to my apps using the country code It will increase the size of the app? I don't wan't have an app that is now 1MB to be 4 or 5 just because of those images.

Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Equal you set diferent languages with the res directories values-es values-fr values ... 
you can set differents drawables for each location with the directories:

drawable-es drawable-fr ... 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Remember that the extra information of the directories has specials importances and you should put in the correct positions http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html
For example, drawable-es-hdpi

The problem of the size of your apk i imagine that you don't need to set all your images diferents for all the countries, isn't it? Normally you only need configure a few images

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to provide resources per country. Check out this answer for details on how to do it: [Localization and drawables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442105/localization-and-drawables)

It will definitely increase the size of your app. It is, like everything else in software development, a compromise between performance (or quality of images) and resouces (in this case, size of apk). To avoid increasing the size of your app exponentially, you can try to provide resources per locale instead of country, or simply, provide only the hdpi version.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to increase the size of your apk with the different drawables, you can code a custom ImageView and set the text over it with a String (that will be translated) or put a textView on top of the ImageView setting them inside a relativelayout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
  android:gravity="center"
  android:orientation="vertical"
 >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/yImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"/>  

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/yTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/yImage"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/yImage"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/yImage"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/yImage"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:lines="2"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It would be easy also with a frame layout.