# Localize resources based on region only

Tags: android, localization, android-resources, android-drawable

I understand how to localize assets based on language and region. As per this post: [Localization and drawables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442105/localization-and-drawables/4442247#4442247)

For example, to target the French speakers in Canada, I would name my folder: 
`drawable-fr-rCA-hdpi`

But what if I only want to target devices that are set to the Canada locale, without worrying about language, would I simply do `drawable-rCA-hdpi`? I have not found any documentation on this and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html, table 2.  Region cannot stand alone.  You must specify either language or language+region.

Comment: Yup! Says it right there "The codes are not case-sensitive; the r prefix is used to distinguish the region portion. You cannot specify a region alone." Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.
Either set `language` or `language+region`, but **not region only**.

In your case, you can duplicate  the resources in `drawable-en-rCA-hdpi` and `drawable-fr-rCA-hdpi`