# Android Localization for resources arabic language

Tags: android, android-studio, localization, android-drawable, android-resources

I want to localize an image Arabic language? How should I accomplish this task?

I have followed [Localization and drawables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442105/localization-and-drawables) but no luck.

Comment: like for example drawable-xxhpdi-ar

Comment: have you created drawable-ar or if need density specific then like "drawable-ar-hdpi" folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localization of drawable-resources is same as string-resources. You need to create **drawable-ar** folder and put image into that folder.

Or if your image in any folder like `drawable-mdpi` then `drawable-ar-mdpi`.

Read detail [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Comment: I open drawable-ar folder and put image into that folder but not working, later in res folder i add new image folders and changed the names.( ex: drawable-mdpi  to drawable-ar-mdpi ) its working now thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can add new android resource folder

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that once you've added your `strings.xml` into the resource file for arabic, ensure your layout is ready for RTL support.

In your manifest file:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:supportsRtl="true" > ....
```

And in all your layout files, ensure you added the left/right and start/end combo. From [Google Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html):

> Change all of your app's "left/right" layout properties to new
> "start/end" equivalents.
>
> If you are targeting your app to Android 4.2
> (the app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 17 or higher), then
> you should use “start” and “end” instead of “left” and “right”. For
> example, android:paddingLeft should become android:paddingStart.
>
> If you want your app to work with versions earlier than Android 4.2 (the
> app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 16 or less), then you
> should add “start” and end” in addition to “left” and “right”. For
> example, you’d use both android:paddingLeft and android:paddingStart.

Once you are done, its quite easy to test it out. Either change your language to arabic, or in the phone's Developer Option, you can force it to show RTL in layout.